# simple algebraic method to solve magic square for children

Tags: linear-algebra

sorry if the question is too noob for this forum.. my 11 years old son was assigned to the task of solve a (kind of) magic square, that can be represented like the following system of equations:

- row $1: 6 + a + b = 11$
- row $2: c + d + 5 = 15$
- row $3: e + 4 + f = 19$
- col $\;\,  1: 6 + c + e = 15$
- col $\;\, 2: a + d + 4 = 16$
- col $\;\, 3: b + 5 + f = 14$

We solved it by writing a small program with a brute-force approach, but I wonder if there is some algebraic method, something more elegant that brute-force but simple enough to be explained to a kid (i. e. simplex matrix manipulations are too complex). Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: I think the easiest way for an 11 yr old to accomplish this is with guess and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have this magic square (the left with letters, the right with empty spaces):

[image]

Remaining numbers for filling the empty spaces are $1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9$.

Let's begin with the first row. The sum of empty spaces in it must be $5 \ (=11-6)$. With the remaining numbers there are only two possibilities how to write $5$ as a sum of two numbers:

$$5 = 2 + 3 \\
  5 = 3 + 2 $$

The first one is impossible:
[image]
because in this case must be in the place of "?" number $10$.

So there is only the second possibility:

[image]

No problem for $11$-year-old child to finish the task now.

Answer (score 1):

From row 1: $b = 5 - a$.

Substitute this into column 3: $5 - a + 5 + f = 14$, i.e. $f = a + 4$.

Substitute this into row 3: $e + 4 + a + 4 = 19$, i.e. $e = 11 - a$.

Substitute this into column 1: $ 6 + c + 11 - a = 15$, i.e. $c = a - 2$.

Substitute this into row 2: $a - 2 + d + 5 = 15$, i.e. $d = 12 - a$.

But this is just what column $2$ says.

So we can take anything for $a$, and we can get $b, c, d, e, f$ from the equations above.

EDIT: Here's an alternative, maybe better for an $11$-year-old.  To find one solution, guess a value for $a$, say $a=0$.  Then one by one we see what values of $b, f, e, c, d$ would get.

Now what would happen if we increased $a$ by $1$?  From row $1$, this would make $b$ decrease by $1$.  From column $3$, that would make $f$ increase by $1$.
From row $3$, that would make $e$ decrease by $1$.  From column $1$, that would make $c$ increase by $1$.  From row $2$, that would make $d$ decrease by $1$.
And column $2$ would still be satisfied.  So you'd have another solution, with each variable increased or decreased by $1$.

Now what if you added an arbitrary amount to $a$?  Again, each of the other variables would increase or decrease by that same arbitrary amount.  So you can make $a$ whatever you want, and find what the other variables would be.